# How do I concatenate a string in a for loop?

Tags: string, for-loop, string-concatenation

I'm trying to specify the file name as a first argument of a function call in the following `for` loop. What I want to achieve is a file name ending with the `i` value at each iteration.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{ 
    imwrite("PHOTO "i" .jpg", frame);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this the minimum amount of code that will reproduce the issue?  You seem to be referencing "frame", but it's not clear what that is.  Also, what language are you writing in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as well as its title to make it more readable and understandable. I removed all the smileys and "thanks" from your question too. When asking, please avoid using them. I provided relevant tags also. There is one question that I cannot answer however: what programming language are you writing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is built in C++, you can use a `stringstream` to build your filenames:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ss.str(std::string()); // Clear the string stream

    ss << "PHOTO" << i << ".jpg";
    imwrite(ss.str(), frame);
}
```

Comment: While this might be a valid answer, I would suggest you to ask OP whether they need C++ code. Probably they're working in pure C, or in C#.

Comment: @dymanoid Fair point, although I based this off one of his previous questions, which involved him using OpenCV in C++.